# Retrieving Data from Firebase in Specific Array Format

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am new to both Angular and Firebase. Still trying to learn the ropes so I am hoping really bad that someone can help me out. I have tried looking through documentations and watching videos but honestly, I still don't get it.

I was able to retrieve my data from firebase using Angular's HTTPCLIENT service. However, it is in the below format:

```
{
    "test01": {
        "title": "News",
        "descr": "Amazing!"
     }
},
     "test02": {
        "title": "Panda",
        "descr": "Amazing!"
     }
}
```

But the problem is that I want to use ngFor to loop through my data so that it will display all the titles and descriptions (regardless of the id) in my homepage. Is there anyway to restructure the data I retrieved into the below format instead so I can loop through it and display the data as it is?

```
favItems = [{id: "test01", title: "News", descr: "Amazing!" }, {id: "test02", title....}]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
let obj = {
  "test01": {
    "title": "News",
    "descr": "Amazing!"
  },
  "test02": {
    "title": "Panda",
    "descr": "Amazing!"
  }
}

let arr = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => {
  return { ...obj[k],
    id: k
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much!